# How to derive syntax of language (From the book Types and Programming Languages)?

Tags: types, syntax, induction

I am reading the book `Types and Programming Languages` by Benjamin C. Pierce. the author talk about deriving syntax for a language in section 3. Section 3.2.3 has the following content.
For each natural number i, define a set S1 as follows

```
S0 = Empty Set
S(i+1) = {true, false, 0} Union {succ t1, pred t1, iszero t1 | t1 in Si}
         Union {if t1 then t2 else t3 | t1, t2, t3 in Si}
Finally, let
S = Union of Si (starting with i = 0)
```

Then the author says that from this we can derive that `S0` is empty.`S1` contains just the constants. `S2` contains the constants **plus the phrases that can be built with constants and just one succ, pred, iszero or if**. What does that mean? How do you derive `S2`

Answer (score 0):

```
(1) S_0 = ∅

(2) S_{i+1} = {true, false, 0} 
              ∪ {succ t1, pred t1, iszero t1 | t1 in Si}
              ∪ {if t1 then t2 else t3 | t1, t2, t3 in S_i}

(3) S = ⋃ {S_i} (starting with i = 0)$
```

This is a way of describing the language inductively using a set builder notation. Each larger indexed `S` will contain sub-terms of smaller indexed `S` terms. Let's work it out to give you an idea.

We know that `S_0` is an empty set so it doesn't contain any terms. `S_1` is a set of constants.

```
S_1 = {true, false, 0}
```

By putting i = 1 in equation (2) we can generate `S_2`

```
S_2 = {true, false, 0} 
    ∪ {succ t1, pred t1, iszero t1 | t1 in S_1}
    ∪ {if t1 then t2 else t3 | t1, t2, t3 in S_1}
```

So `S_2` would be a set containing terms:

```
S_2 = { true, false, 0, 
        succ true, pred true, iszero true, succ false, pred false, 
        iszero false,  succ zero, pred zero, iszero zero, 
        if true then true else true, if true then true else t3 false, 
        if true then true else t3 zero, if true then false else t3 true, 
        ..., if false then zero else zero, if zero then zero else zero}
```

Notice, the sub-terms of terms in S_2 can only be terms from S_1 i.e. constants. Hence there will only be one occurrence of succ, pred, iszero and if.

`S_3` will contain the terms such that terms of `S_2` and `S_1` are its sub-terms. So it can have 1 or 2 occurrences of succ, pred, iszero and if.

Essentially you can think of `t1` as a hole in the `S_{i+1}` template where
you can plug in `S_{i}` terms. Finally, the complete language `S` is the union of all such S_i terms.

Comment: Right! but the author says `S2 contains the constants plus the phrases that can be built with constants and just one succ, pred, iszero or if.`
 Why **..just one succ, pred, iszero or if** ?

Comment: That’s because subterms of terms of S_2 can only belong to S_1 i.e. constants. so S_2 will have only one succ, pred iszero or if, as you can see from the S_2 set I have explicitly written down.